# Hammer.js pan event only for touch devices and not for desktop computer Click+Drag

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, hammer.js

I use this standard code for Pan / Pinch *(1)* with Hammer.js :

```
var mc = new Hammer(document.body);

mc.add(new Hammer.Pinch({ threshold: 0 })).recognizeWith(mc.get('pan'));

// let the pan gesture support all directions. this will block the vertical scrolling on a touch-device while on the element
mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
mc.on("panleft panright panup pandown tap press pinchstart pinchmove", function(ev) {
    $('#myElement').text(ev.type +" gesture detected. ev.scale=" + ev.scale + "  ev.deltaX,Y=" + ev.deltaX +'  ' + ev.deltaY);
});
```

**How to get the hammer.js pan events *only for touch devices* and not for desktop computer `Click+Drag`?** (because I have already working code for desktop computer click+drag, and I don't want to rewrite this!)

*Note (1)* : *By the way, is this code good?, why is the `recognizeWith` really needed?* :

Answer (score 9):

You may force Hammer.js to use the input class that you want by setting *inputClass* option:

```
var hammer = Hammer(element, {
  inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput
})
```

You may want also to support pointer events when available:

```
var hammer = Hammer(element, {
  inputClass: Hammer.SUPPORT_POINTER_EVENTS ? Hammer.PointerEventInput : Hammer.TouchInput
})
```

Hammer.js has following inputClasses built in:

- PointerEventInput
- TouchInput
- MouseInput
- TouchMouseInput

Answer (score 6):

You can check 'pointerType' property value in event (ev) object.
It should be "mouse" for desktop.