# Double tap, also a double click is being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I simply would like to implement double tap on my double click event.
the problem is doubletap overwrite double click event.

I have no problem running the event double tap on ipad.
It works great with hammer. On desktop `dblclick` and `doubletap` are both triggered.

So i have to replace dblclick by doubletap ans it is not very clear to read DoubleTap and dblclick be triggered.
If I put the two events, my code is executed twice. (http://jsfiddle.net/8vHjj/14/)

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var hammer = new Hammer(output);


hammer.on("doubletap", function() {
        output.innerText += " / doubletap";
    });

$("#output").on("dblclick", function(){
     output.innerText += " / doubleclick";
});
```

Is there a solution that would have both events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect double tap on ipad or iphone screen using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825144/detect-double-tap-on-ipad-or-iphone-screen-using-javascript)

Comment: I have no problem running the event double tap on ipad. It works great with hammer. On desktop dblclick and DoubleTap are both triggered.

Comment: You can remove `dblclick` and leave only `doubletap` that will be triggered both on mobile and desktop, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

This topic help me :
[Hammer.js pan event only for touch devices and not for desktop computer Click+Drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319994/hammer-js-pan-event-only-for-touch-devices-and-not-for-desktop-computer-clickdr).

To trigger doubleTap only on touch device, we can use inputClass option

```
var hammer = Hammer(element, {
  inputClass: Hammer.SUPPORT_POINTER_EVENTS ? Hammer.PointerEventInput : Hammer.TouchInput
})
```

I found no API, which explain this option. 
The doc "hammer" does not mention the "input Class"